# Retrieve Google Polygons LatLng Coordinates

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis, polygon

When you search an area on Google Maps (eg.London) it shows you a highlighted polygon of London. What I need to do is to retrieve the LatLng coordinates of this polygon. Looking on Google's API Documentation I didn't find anything matching that need. Is it possible in another way/ workaround to do it?

Answer (score -1):

With regards to the highlighted polygon (boundaries) like **maps.google.com** does, this is not yet available in Google Maps Platform APIs, however, there is a popular Feature Request with almost **400 stars** in our Google Issue Tracker. I suggest you to star this feature request and to receive notifications about further updates of this feature. Here's the feature request **[Feature: Automatic polygon generation to specified geographic boundary (e.g. state, country)](https://issuetracker.google.com/35816953)**.

On the other hand, you can check this **[documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays)** to get the latlng points of the polygon.

Hope this information find you helpful and good luck on your application!